# JS - $ is not defined & cannot call method "plug" of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a drop down menu system in html and css, however the js is displaying the following errors for my two js files when I inspect element > Console in Chrome:

1. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  for filters.js`
2. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  for jquery.min.js`

The drop down menu does not display as it should.

I have my html page with the  tags at the bottom, before  and it loads like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/filters.js"></script>
```

Here is the js for files.js

```
$(function() {
  /**
   * the element
   */
  var $ui = $('#ui_element');
  /**
   * on focus and on click display the dropdown,
   * and change the arrow image
   */
  $ui.find('.sb_input').bind('focus click', function() {
    $ui.find('.sb_down').addClass('sb_up').removeClass('sb_down').andSelf().find('.sb_dropdown').show();
  });
  /**
   * on mouse leave hide the dropdown,
   * and change the arrow image
   */
  $ui.bind('mouseleave', function() {
    $ui.find('.sb_up').addClass('sb_down').removeClass('sb_up').andSelf().find('.sb_dropdown').hide();
  });
  /**
   * selecting all checkboxes
   */
  $ui.find('.sb_dropdown').find('label[for="all"]').prev().bind('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked).attr('disabled', this.checked);
  });
});
```

Here's the js for jquery.min.js

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu=(function(){var b=$("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"),g=b.children("a"),c=$("body"),d=-1;function f(){g.on("click",a);b.on("click",function(h){h.stopPropagation()})}function a(j){if(d!==-1){b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen")}var i=$(j.currentTarget).parent("li"),h=i.index();if(d===h){i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");d=-1}else{i.addClass("cbp-hropen");d=h;c.off("click").on("click",e)}return false}function e(h){b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");d=-1}return{init:f}})();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have the jQuery file in your project at the right place? It normally comes when jQuery is missing.

Comment: If yes, please confirm that you are using jQuery only after jQuery is executed. That is, to execute your custom script which uses jQuery, you must include jQuery before your script.

Comment: "Here's the js for jquery.min.js" -- so you are storing that code in jquery.min.js? You should store your code with a different filename and include the jquery source in jquery.min.js

Comment: Ananthan is exactly right...Put <script scr='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script> at the top of your document.

Comment: Answer below fixed the issue and the drop down does display now.

Sorry for not responding sooner, I honestly didn't except answer so fast! You guys rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery.min.js should be something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You are using the incorrect jquery code. Jquery is what defines `$`, which is why it is not working in your javascript code.

Simply replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or the link to a version of the JQuery code.

Comment: Great, works now - thanks!

Why would I still be getting this error thought:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'plug' of null

Comment: @user3370902 There is no such a method into the posted code. Anyway, this error means that the object from which you call the method is undefined (does not exist). Check and let us know.

Comment: Found out this error is not related to the dropdown menu.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3370902 As an example, try : `var a = {}; a.b.m(); // a.b is not defined`.

Comment: Oh no... Please don't post code into comments... Remove them then post a new question @user3370902.